# Manter sequência do código depois do refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Gostaria de saber como manter minha sequências de comandos após atualizar a página, pois o meu javascript assim que é carregado age como se fosse a primeira vez.
A ideia é checar uma condição (Hp), atualizar a página e clicar em um botão.
Algo parecido com o que o imacros faz.

```
var energy  =   Number(document.getElementById("infobar_energy").getElementsByClassName("infobar_line_value")[0].innerHTML.replace("&nbsp;","").replace("/&nbsp;","/").slice(0,document.getElementById("infobar_energy").getElementsByClassName("infobar_line_value")[0].innerHTML.replace("&nbsp;","").replace("/&nbsp;","/").indexOf('/')));
var server = 'https://s103-br.bitefight.gameforge.com';
if (energy > 0 ){
    if (window.location.href.includes("/humanhunt/humanHunt/2?__token=")){
        window.location.href = server + "/robbery/index"; 
    }
    if (window.location.href.includes("/humanhunt/index")){
        document.getElementsByClassName("btn-right")[3].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
    }else{
        window.location.href = server + "/humanHunt/index"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: O que seria essa 'sequência de comandos' ?

Comment: Tu já usou o imacros? Basicamente é como se fosse seguir uma receita de bolo passo a passo, primeiro vai chegar uma condição caso a condição for verdadeira vai seguir os passos. Quando atualizar a página ele vai continuar de onde parou sem checar as condições anteriores

Comment: Mas é uma array? Imagino que a solução seja salvar em coockies.

Comment: @Bananaz Não, nunca usei. Você tem o código que está usando ou não fez nenhum código ainda?

Comment: eu fiz um script rapido baseado no jogo bitefight, a minha ideia é checar se tem energia, se houver entao ele vai ir para o link "/robbery/index", depois vai clicar no botao de caçar e voltar para pagina de luta.
porem o unico modo que achei foi esse, checar toda hora o link pra tomar a decisão seguinte